# MEAN stack setup issues

Tags: git, mongodb, mean-stack

I am currently trying to get a MEAN server set up on my laptop

Seem to be having trouble right off the bat.. I'm following the instructions on mean.io

When I get to the step that says to run Grunt, I get the following errors:

```
Running "hook" task
>> Starting hooked tasks.

Running "clean:0" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
>> 42 files lint free.

Running "csslint:src" (csslint) task
>> 5 files lint free.

Running "concurrent:tasks" (concurrent) task
Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
[nodemon] v1.2.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
debugger listening on port 5858

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'meanio'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/noel/noelissa/server.js:12:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I've tried looking around for answers online but can't seem to find anything that works..

Also, I have installed Node.js, MongoDB and Git

Comment: Did you install the dependencies with `npm install`?

Answer (score 0):

npm install meanio

maybe it was not installed properly, install missing dependencies or run again

npm install